# how to create php echo via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to create the echo via AJAX on a simple form but i do not succeed in it.

This is the form and js:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $(document).on('click', '.subscribe_newsletter', function()
    {       

        $('#subscribe_newsletter').val($(this).val());
            var data = $("#subscribe").serialize();

        $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'email_subscribe.php',
        data : data,
        success :  function(data)
               {                        
                    $("#subscribe").fadeOut(500).hide(function()
                    {
                        $(".subscribe_wrapper").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                        {
                            $(".subscribe_wrapper").html(data);

                        });


                    });

               }
        });
        return false;
    });  

});
</script>
<div id="form" class="subscribe_wrapper">
   <form id="subscribe" method="POST">
      <input name="email_subscribe" type="text" />
      <input class="subscribe_newsletter" type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
   </form>
</div>
```

This is **email_subscribe.php**

```
// subscribe 
if (isset($_POST['email_subscribe'])) {   
   $email_add = $_POST['email_subscribe'] . ',' . "\n";
   $store = file_put_contents('database-email.txt', $email_add, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
   if($store === false) {
     die('There was an error writing to this file');
   }
   else {
     echo "$email_add successfully added!";
   }
}
```

The echo does not appear and neither the email is stored in the text file. 
Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Well then maybe `$_POST['email_subscribe']` wasn’t set, in which case your PHP code would do _nothing else_ whatsoever ...

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the server side or in the console?

Comment: I think your form is submitting before your AJAX request is firing.  try adding a `'e.preventDefault()` to your JS, and pass in `e` to the click handler function

Comment: I agree, this was a mistake. But it still does not work

Comment: Remove the form tags and use only the inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your Javascript code with this

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.subscribe_newsletter').click(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

        $('#subscribe_newsletter').val($(this).val());
            var data = $("#subscribe").serialize();

        $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'email_subscribe.php',
        data : data,
        success :  function(data)
               {
                    $("#subscribe").fadeOut(500).hide(function()
                    {
                        $(".subscribe_wrapper").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                        {
                            $(".subscribe_wrapper").html(data);

                        });


                    });

               }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Note that I have replaced `$(document).on('click', '.subscribe_newsletter', function()` with `$('.subscribe_newsletter').click(function(e)` and added `e.preventDefault();` on the line below

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

Try to change

```
$(document).on('click', '.subscribe_newsletter', function()
```

to

```
$(".subscribe_newsletter").click(function (e)
```

and add

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modify your code in this way:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $(document).on('click', '.subscribe_newsletter', function()
    {       
      var data =  $('#email_subscribe').val();
        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'email_subscribe.php',
        data : {email_subscribe: data},
        success :  function(data)
               {                        
                    $("#subscribe").fadeOut(500).hide(function()
                    {
                        $(".subscribe_wrapper").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                        {
                            $(".subscribe_wrapper").html(data);
                        });
                    });
               }
        });
        return false;
    });  
});
</script>
<div id="form" class="subscribe_wrapper">
   <form id="subscribe" method="POST">
      <input id="email_subscripe" name="email_subscribe" type="text" />
      <input class="subscribe_newsletter" type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
   </form>
</div>
```